# Code containing array definitions working great in main function, but not when I include it from a separate file, why?

Tags: c, arrays, string, include

So I have this code, which builds an array of strings (23 strings of different sizes).
To do so, I defined each string separately like this:

```
char text1[] = "The content of string 1\n";
char text2[] = "The content of string 2 which is longer\n";
```

And similarly for the 21 remaining strings. Then I defined 23 pointers to char, for every string, like this:

```
char *ptext1 = text1; 
char *ptext2 = text2;
```

And similarly for the 21 remaining strings. Then I defined an array of pointers to char, and initialized it with 23 pointers to I just created:

```
char *parray[23];
parray[0] = ptext1;
parray[1] = ptext2; // ...etc.
```

Now, to access the strings by index, I iterate over the elements with a for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 23; i++)
{
        printf("%s", parray[i]);
}
```

This code works like a charm in the main function, however, when I moved all the string and pointers and array definitions to a header file (because I thought it's a good practice to have definitions out of the way, right?) and included it in the main.c file, where I just have the for loop, it didn't work. The compiler shows all kinds of warnings and errors like:

```
warning: Data definition has to type or storage class (Then it shows this line:) parray[0] = text1;
error: Conflicting types for 'parray'
note: Previous declaration of 'parray' was here: char *parray[23];
error: Invalid Initialized parray[0] = text1;
```

And it continues to show similar warnings and errors for all the 23 elements.

So why is this code working like I want it in the main function, but not when I include it?

Note:

I am using mingw gcc compiler for windows, when I compile, I use this command:`gcc main.c`
and the header file is of course in the same directory.

Here is a copy/past or the error output:

```
In file included from x.c:2:0:
x.h:15:2: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
  parray[0] = ptext11;
  ^
x.h:15:2: error: conflicting types for 'parray'
x.h:13:8: note: previous declaration of 'parray' was here
  char *parray[2];
        ^
x.h:15:2: error: invalid initializer
  parray[0] = ptext11;
  ^
x.h:16:2: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
  parray[1] = ptext12;
  ^
x.h:16:2: error: conflicting types for 'parray'
x.h:13:8: note: previous declaration of 'parray' was here
  char *parray[2];
        ^
x.h:16:2: error: invalid initializer
  parray[1] = ptext12;
  ^
```

And here is the main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"


void main(void)
{

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", parray[i]);
    }
}
```

And the main.h file:

```
char text11[] = "Content of string 1";

char text12[] = "Content of string 2, which is longer";


char *ptext11 = text11, *ptext12 = text12;

char *parray[2];

parray[0] = ptext11;
parray[1] = ptext12;
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your issue.

Comment: you've got typographic errors in that error message, any chance you can cut and paste it instead of trying to transcribe it manually.

Comment: `text1` and `text2` are `char`s that can hold just one character.

Comment: @CoolGuy, no, text1 and text2 are strings, I tested this code, works like I want

Comment: Look at what you've posted. `char text1="..."` and `char text2=".."`. These are not an array of characters.

Comment: @CoolGuy, sorry yeah you're right, but in the original code used char text1[] = " ..."; i'll correct it in this post

Comment: Please post your actual code. your error message says `parray[0] = text1;` but your code says `parray[0] = ptext1;`

Comment: @SouravGhosh, here, I posted the actual code

Comment: Please should the full header (`x.h`). There seems to be something terribly wrong. You cannot put statements like `a=b;` into a header/out of any context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C statements like:

```
parray[0] = ptext11;
parray[1] = ptext12;
```

may not appear outside a context, that is may only appear inside a function.

To initiialise `parray` on definition do:

```
char *parray[2] = {ptext11, ptext12};
```

---

**Update:**

Assuming this

```
char text11[] = "Content of string 1";
char text12[] = "Content of string 2, which is longer";
char *ptext11 = text11, *ptext12 = text12;
```

the code can even be shortened to this:

```
char *parray[2] = 
{
  "Content of string 1",
  "Content of string 2, which is longer"
};
```

or to the more convenient version:

```
char *parray[] = 
{
  "Content of string 1",
  "Content of string 2, which is longer",
  NULL
};
```

The `NULL` indicates the end of the array and can be use to determine the number of elements on run-time. This allows you to add more strings to the array in newer versions of your code without being in the need to adjust any varibale defining the size of the array.

An example of a function determing the number of elements would be:

```
ssize_t number_of_array_elements(char ** parray)
{
  ssize_t result = 0;

  if (NULL == *parray)
  {
    result = -1;
    errno = EINVAL;
  }
  else
  {
    while (NULL != *parray)
    {
      ++result;
      ++parray;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


char * parray[] = {
  "Content of string 1",
  "Content of string 2, which is longer",
  NULL
};

int main(void)
{
  size_t size = 0;

  {
    ssize_t result = number_of_array_elements(parray);
    if (-1 == result)
    {
      perror("array_elements() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size = result;
  }

  printf("parray holds %zu elements.\n", size);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: yes, thank you sir @alk, but I was wondering what documentation have this information? I didn't know this till now. ( Note that I am new to C)

Comment: @the-sizixe: It might probably be described in the 1st chapter of your preferred CV primer? If it isn't switch to another book.

Comment: I see, can you recommend me a book? That teaches C, not programming. I want to enhance my C skills, with knowledge like this.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `text1` is a single `char`. What you want in an array of `char`s.

Change your code

```
char text1 = "The content of string 1\n";
```

and

```
char *parray[23];
parray[0] = ptext1;
parray[1] = ptext2; // ...etc.
```

to

```
char text1[] = "The content of string 1\n";
char *ptext1 = text1;
```

and

```
char **parray= NULL;
parray = malloc(23 * sizeof (*parray));
parray[0] = ptext1;
parray[1] = ptext2; // ...etc.
```

and, in the end, `free(parray)`.

Note: use of `char *ptext1` and family is redundant. Using the corrected version. you can directly write something like `parray[0] = text1` and so on.

---

EDIT:

AS per your latest edit, it seems you're trying to initialize each element of the array *one-by-one* in the header file. This is not allowed. Putting the array in the header file makes the scope of the array as global. You can initialize an global array only at the declaration/definition time using `char *parray[23] = {<set of initializers>}`, not afterwards. You cannot do

```
parray[0] = ptext1;
parray[1] = ptext2;
```

in a header file [global scope]. Otherwise, you've to do that from inside your function.

Comment: But why my code works in main, but not when included separately? If it worded once, it should work again, non?

Comment: @the-sizixe your code was different than what you're posted here. see the error message `parray[0] = text1;` but what you posted is `parray[0] = ptext1;`. Check your code properly.

Comment: Besides the change the OP applied after you posted your answer, I do not see how switching from a statically allocated array to a dynamical one might solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @alk sir, the main issue was with `text1` vs. `text1[]` and `char *ptext1 = text1`. Dynamic allocation can be considered as a suggestion.

Comment: @alk Sir, there seems to be a major conceptual issue with OP's post. Please check my updated answer.